# How can I make deep links clickable on Google Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, deep-linking

I am trying to save a deep link in my calendar and make it clickable.

My URI has a format like
`appname://timer?2000sec&ringtone?jinglebells`.

On iOS, in the Calendar, I see it properly. It shows the text in red and if I click it, it opens the app. This, btw, is under "notes", not in the URL field.

On Android however this does not seem to be working properly, the Deep Link is not recognized. It works in other places! I know if the info.plist has a wrong name for the scheme it won't recognize, but I created an HTML page with the `appname://` as hyperlink, and if I open it in chrome and click it, it does exactly what it is supposed to, so the AndroidManifest.xml should be set up correctly. But unless I specifically mark it as a Link (be it hyperlink or anything else) it is seen by Android as plane text.

Now, is there a way to force Android to see it as something clickable in the notes field in the Calendar?

Side info:

```
<!-- Deep linking, this is under the mainActivity <activity> tag -->
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="rheinbahnnextgen" />
```

I am using flutter for this, the package I am using is https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar

Comment: There is no single "Calendar" app for Android. There are dozens of them, both pre-installed and user-installed. Their behavior will vary.

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant the google calendar, I adjusted the title accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As I just found out, Google Calendar supports hyperlinks

`<a href="appname://timer?2000sec&ringtone?jinglebells/">link</a>`